# Difference between On-Prem SQL and Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am working on POC to move production databases from existing on-prem SQL Server 2008 into Azure SQL.

Details and links on identifying the differences are most welcome!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the help on how to ask questions as your question is not a good fit for SO.  (An example of a good question would be, after you read up on the differences and tried to run an Azure query, posting your before / after versions of the query and the expected output vs actual output or error message you get)

Comment: There is no such version as SQL Server 2010.

Comment: @Dan Yes, i wanted to mention SQL server 2012. And, I got more info on the same. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can find latest info on what is in Azure SQL Database and how it matches up with SQL Server here : [What's new with SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-whats-new/)